# How does my Clock widget reacts immediately on AlarmChange

Tags: android, widget

As a beginning Android programmer I am trying to build a Clock Widget in which a TextView reacts immediately to an Alarm setting Change, instead after the 30 minutes auto APPWIDGET_UPDATE.
Did a lot of research about this but did not find a working solution.
I did expect to find an Intent-filter for in the manifest.xml but I couldn't find an appropriate filter.
In the manifest at the widget receiver I tried among other filters:

```
  <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET" />
      <action android:name="intent.extra.ALARM_COUNT" />
  </intent-filter>
```

As I understand a change in the Alarm setting should put or change an extra Integer at the String EXTRA_ALARM_COUNT and I expected to receive this Extra Integer in the onReceive().

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)   {
    if (intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_ALARM_COUNT, 0) > 0 ) {
        Log.w("onReceive", "Alarm is changed " + intent.getAction());
    }
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
}
```

This however doesn't give any results.
What do I miss or do wrong?
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

As a novice android programmer, I was looking too difficult for a solution while it seems to be quite easy.

The right intent-filter for the widgetprovider in the manifest is:

```
<action android:name="android.app.action.NEXT_ALARM_CLOCK_CHANGED" />
```

In the widgetprovider add:

```
 public static final String ALARM_CLOCK_CHANGED = "android.app.action.NEXT_ALARM_CLOCK_CHANGED";
```

In the widget onReceive()

```
    String action = intent.getAction();
    assert action != null;
    if ((action.equals(ALARM_CLOCK_CHANGED))) {
        // get new next alarm here
    }
```

Thank you & best regards